# css .active dropdown selects all links

Tags: css, dropdown

I'm using bootstrap navwalker to show my menu. But when i use the .active tag to on a dropdown link all the elements get te the tag. (as show in the picture)

[image]

(only "Jeugd bestuur" and "Bestuur" sould be red. since i am on that page.)

this i my nav:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                    <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                            'depth'             => 2,
                            'container'         => 'div',
                            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                            'container_id'      => 'navbarNavDropdown',
                            'menu_class'        => 'nav',
                            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

and with this CSS i'm trying to get the active tag

```
.header ul li.active a  {
    background-color: #FE0000;
    border-radius: 10%;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6 );
    color: #ffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does this because you've told it to. `li.active a` means "all `a` tags that are descendants of `li` tags with the `active` class", and submenus in WordPress are structured like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So the `li` for any menu item with a submenu also contains all the `a` tags for links in those submenus.

To only the first link inside a menu item you need to use the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
.header ul li.active > a {}
```